# Why does this error occur when using SingleAsync?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Find if an item is duplicated.
Expected: an exception to be thrown only if more than one item is found. but we get a different exception here?

```
        try
        {
            // Find duplicate item
            duplicateItem = await _context.Items
                .SingleAsync(m => m.UserId == userId && m.Name == "some item");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
    //Exception more than one item found
        }
```

> [01:48:06 ERR] An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type '....ApplicationDbContext'.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Source sequence doesn't contain any elements.
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Single_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Single.cs:line 136
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
>      at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line 98
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Source sequence doesn't contain any
>   elements.    at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Single_[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1
>   source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Single.cs:line 136
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.TaskResultAsyncEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Select.cs:line 106
>
>   at
>   System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\AsyncIterator.cs:line
>   98    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery[TResult](QueryContext
>   queryContext, Func`2 compiledQuery, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type
>   contextType)

Comment: `Single[Async]` will throw if there is zero or multiple items, I don't get your question here.

Comment: Side note: if you want to check does collection has duplicates it can be done without exceptions. Just `.Where(<your condition>).Take(2).ToList()` and then simply check a length of that list

Comment: @AleksAndreev Fun fact, calling `Single` in Entity Framework does a `Take(2)` anyway...

Comment: Use `SingleOrDefaultAsync` instead, `Single` expects one and only one entity that matches the condition you give it (exactly one), while `SingleOrDefault` expects *at most* one matched entity (zero or one).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are confusing `SingleAsync` with `SingleOrDefaultAsync`.

`SingleAsync` -> means that it will throw if no entries or more than one entry is found

> Asynchronously returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a
>   specified condition, and throws an exception if more than one such
>   element exists.

`SingleOrDefaultAsync` -> means that it will throw if two or more entries are found

> Asynchronously returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a
>   specified condition or a default value if no such element exists; this
>   method throws an exception if more than one element satisfies the
>   condition.